# Cannot parse json with two different data types in retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to parse this json bellow, into a object named `AlbumResponse` that have another two objects inside, `Album` and `PaginationInfo`. Retrofit version 2.0

```
[
    {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "King Stays King",
        "artist_name":"Timbaland",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "East Atlanta Santa 2",
        "artist_name":"Gucci Mane",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "The cuban connect",
        "artist_name":"Phophit",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Shmoney Keeps",
        "artist_name":"Calling",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Cabin Fever 3",
        "artist_name":"Wiz khalifa",
        "image":""
    }
],
{
    "nextPage": "http://private-ede172-mymixtapez1.apiary-mock.com/features/page_3/",
    "itemsTotal": 10,
    "page": 2,
    "pagerMax": 2
}
```

Album class

```
public class Album {
    long id;
    String name;
    @SerializedName("artist_name")
    String artistName;
    String image;
}
```

PaginationInfo class

```
public class PaginationInfo {
    int page;
    int pagerMax;
    int nextPage;
    int itemsTotal;
}
```

AlbumResponse, that have both classes above inside, and `Album` is a `List`

```
public class AlbumResponse {
    public List<Album> albums;
    public PaginationInfo paginationInfo;
}
```

The request

```
Call<AlbumResponse> responseCall = albumService.features();
responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<AlbumResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<AlbumResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if(response.isSuccess()) {
            AlbumResponse albumResponse = response.body();
            PaginationInfo paginationInfo = albumResponse.getPaginationInfo();

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Interface

```
public interface AlbumService {
  @GET("/features/")
  Call<AlbumResponse> features();
}
```

The problem is that im getting a `Throwable` that contains:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $`

Please, can someone help me, i not found any answers in stackoverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON have a trouble in initial declaration.

According [json.org](http://www.json.org/):

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> • A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>   realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>   list, or associative array.
>
> • An ordered list of values. In most
>   languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

Try update your JSON to:

```
"albums": [
    {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "King Stays King",
        "artist_name":"Timbaland",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "East Atlanta Santa 2",
        "artist_name":"Gucci Mane",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "The cuban connect",
        "artist_name":"Phophit",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Shmoney Keeps",
        "artist_name":"Calling",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Cabin Fever 3",
        "artist_name":"Wiz khalifa",
        "image":""
    }
],
"pagination_info": 
{
    "nextPage": "http://private-ede172-mymixtapez1.apiary-mock.com/features/page_3/",
    "itemsTotal": 10,
    "page": 2,
    "pagerMax": 2
}
```

Comment: Yes, it work like a charm, the problem is in the `JSON`, NOT in the `RETROFIT` . It was a begginer mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error says: the Parser expected a JSON-Object but it reads a JSON-array. To fix it (if you control the server) you should change the JSON String to something like this:

```
{
  "albums" : [
    {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "King Stays King",
        "artist_name":"Timbaland",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "East Atlanta Santa 2",
        "artist_name":"Gucci Mane",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "The cuban connect",
        "artist_name":"Phophit",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Shmoney Keeps",
        "artist_name":"Calling",
        "image":""
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Cabin Fever 3",
        "artist_name":"Wiz khalifa",
        "image":""
    }
],
 "paginationInfo" : {
    "nextPage": "http://private-ede172-mymixtapez1.apiary-mock.com/features/page_3/",
    "itemsTotal": 10,
    "page": 2,
    "pagerMax": 2
 }
}
```

Now it's a JSON-Object and is conform to your Java class.

If you cannot change the JSON on the backend, I would take it as row response and parse the `albums Array` and the `PaginationInfo` separately using GSON or manually.

Btw. you must change the `nextPage` type from `int` to `String` in the `PaginationInfo` class

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. The json is static in my server, and i did this mistake. Thanks.